# manage order of static link for IOS in XCode

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

**QUESTION:** how to manage linking order in xcode?

---

**DETAILES:**
I'm new in Apple-dev and have some troubles with building my project for ios.
I'm building OGRE3d(1.10) and MyGUI(3.2) libraries from source code via cmake and ios-toolchain.cmake.
MyGUI using functions from ogre and I like them using cmake function target_link_library. And I have any .a static libraries. We will name them ogre.a and mygui.a.

Then I've create ios project and create Objective-c++ file(.mm) where tried to use mygui and ogre function. To link mygui and ogre i've drag them and drop to the root of project structure of xcode and i see them in "linked framework and libraries".

But I have linking errors, which says that ogre function can't be linked to MyGUI (undefined symbols).
As I think the reason of the errors is wrong linking order of the libraries. 
So, I tried to move the order on the project struct, but nothing changed. It seems that changing order libraries in project struct doesn't change linking order. So how can i manage it?

---

I've seen the same [question](http://www.ogre3d.org/addonforums/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=30342) on OGRE forum.
But there is no answer :(

Comment: maybe you can create different targets where the second one depends on the first one. if you build the second one, it first builds the first one before so the linking should be possible